# map is not displaying from pagerfragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-mapview, fragmentpageradapter

I am having a problem in displaying google map defined on a fragment.

here is my code:

**1. Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="a.b.c">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**2. MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        //Get Location Permission
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                    {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);

        }

        // Tab to get Date TODO: Expand fo both Location and Date
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showDateDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    public void showDateDialog() {
        DialogFragment CalFragment = new CalFragment();
        CalFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch (pos) {

                case 0:
                    return FirstFragment.newInstance("FirstFragment, Instance 1");
                case 1:
                    return SecondFragment.newInstance();
                case 2:
                    return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 1");
                case 3:
                    return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 2");
                case 4:
                    return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Instance 3");
                default:
                    return ThirdFragment.newInstance("ThirdFragment, Default");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

**2.a activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.phocast.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"   />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My map is defined in secondfragment as:

**3. SecondFragment.java**

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public GoogleMap getMap() {
    return mMap;
    }
    public static SecondFragment newInstance() {
        SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, null, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

**3.a. fragment_second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and **build.gradel** is:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
```

I also have created `google_maps_api.xml` in android studio, just to add the key here.

The code is compiled and running without any error, with blank screen in second fragment, where I am expecting the map with a marker to be shown.

Where I am going wrong?

in the logcat, I have received this error:

> 02-12 23:16:17.246 7931-7931/com.example.phocast
>   E/Google Maps Android API: Google Maps Android API v2 only supports
>   devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above

**NB**Before asked, for last few days, when I am putting code snippet, I have been asked for full code, MVT only once. So, please pardon me putting the full code, which made the post bit big

Comment: try it in a real phone dont use emulater

Comment: can this really be the cause?

Comment: I had the same problem ....didn't work in emulator ...just in my phone

Comment: unfortunately for my phone its showing insufficient permission, dont know why. But on first look, do you think the code is ok?

Comment: it seem that ..post your logs

Comment: insufficient permission?

Comment: yes...i dont know why. basically I cannot chose camera mode while i connected the device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164989/discussion-between-tigo2018-and-barud).